# Changing GRUB_TIMEOUT value doesn’t seem to work

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, lubuntu

Yes, I did do `sudo update-grub`.

Changing the `/etc/default/grub GRUB_TIMEOUT` variable seems to work once, but then after that first time every time I reboot the timeout is 30 seconds and my time I set is ignored.

I am running Lubuntu and Windows 7. GRUB2 came with Lubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be an issue connected to `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT`. According to [the official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Last_Boot_Failed_or_Boot_into_Recovery_Mode) — which is still relevant to Lubunt u— it says:

> If the last boot failed or after a boot into Recovery Mode the menu will be displayed until the user makes a selection.
>
> To change this behaviour, edit /etc/default/grub and add the variable GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT. Set the value similar to setting for GRUB_TIMEOUT.
>
> 1. For -1, there will be no countdown and thus the menu will display.
> 2. For 0, menu will not display even for a failed startup.
> 3. For >=1, menu will display for the specified number of seconds.
>
> Run update-grub after the change have been made.

It could be that your setup is somehow just powering down and/or rebooting Lubuntu in a way that makes it feel that the last boot failed — or the system crashed — thus it’s going to look for the `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` value and use it’s default value if it’s not set elsewhere.

Regardless, here is how I tweak that `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` value.

First, open up `/etc/default/grub` using `nano`—or you can use whatever text editor you like—like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then I set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and then `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` like this:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
```

Note that I am setting `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` with a variable reference to `$GRUB_TIMEOUT` instead of setting a new number; feel free to change that to a real number if you need different timeout values.

Then I update GRUB and all should be good:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: seems to work. "sudo update-grub" seems to work too.

Comment: In my generated /boot/grub/grub.cfg with stock Ubuntu 20.04, I see that for some reason all linux boot lines include the "recordfail" command, so they all seem to trigger this behavior. I don't know why. But this answer does fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Does not work on latest 20.04 version of Ubuntu.